# Lag when playing Rust

Tags: steam, pc, rust

Yesterday I bought Rust on Steam, I downloaded and installed it without any problem. When I try to join a server to play, it stays on the loading screen for about 20 minutes and when the game finally starts it is extremely laggy, and I can't play at all.

I would like to know what the problem is.

I don't think the problem is due to my PC, as I can play Skyrim in ultra.

Comment: That are not enough information, give us your PC specs and so on.. btw Skyrim on ultra dont mean much in 2015

Comment: I don't know exactly right now, but HD7700, I5, 6GB RAM. I tried to launch Rust in poor graphic but i didn't work too.

Comment: By extremely laggy, do you mean poor framerate or extremely high ping? Both are entirely different problems with entirely different causes.

Comment: Extremly high ping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, your specs are not too good.

The issue with the loading screen is probably due to the slowness of your hard disk, it might have problems if the HDD is almost full.

The specs are kinda low, the problem with Indie games is that they are usually less optimized then triple A games. Also, remember that Skyrim came out in 2011! ( God I'm old )

It could also be a CPU/RAM problem, can you give us your CPU specs?

Also try to open the task manager ( Ctrl + Shit + Esc ) and watch your RAM/CPU consumption.

Have you tried closing everything else before playing the game? ( Especially close Google Chrome since it likes to devour a lot of RAM )

Comment: I have never ever had any problem with any games, my CPU and RAM consuption is normal. I don't use any other application at the same time. I can't give you specs now I'm at work

Comment: i would start with driver updates. a loading screen of 20min in a game like rust hasn't to do anything with a slow or nearly full hdd. Then try thinks like disabling firewall and antivir-live-scans after that give us feedback

Comment: Don't worry, give them when you have time. Again, Skyrim isn't really a high consumption game.
http://systemrequirementslab.com/cyri?gameName=rust&itemId=11932&p=r
Rust wants minimum 4 GB of ram and reccomend 8GB, whils skyrim wants minimum 2 GB and reccomends at least 4.

Comment: @Nitro.de Good idea with the anti-virus. In my opinion loading screen has to do with a slow HDD, or more specific, it has to do a lot with the reading speed of the Hard disk. That's why installing a game on a SDD reduces the loading of the game by a ridicolous amount.

Comment: I'll give them later, and I already did a driver update few weeks ago. I even try to lauch the old version of the game and didn't work too. I can play dragon age inquisition, farcry 4 and more recent games without issues..

Comment: @Maxime But you forget that Rust is an Indie game. As Jubatus mentioned isn't Rust well optimized which can make such problems sometime. However is driver update "few weeks ago" means you're not on the latest driver (I'm 99.9999% sure). And Jubatus you're right with the HDD/SDD read/write thing but you shouldn't forget that rust has a multiplayer focus so it's possible that the game isn't just "loading" in the loadingscreen but downloading stuff and connecting to the server and/or the other poeple on it. (Dont know if rust is using P2P or dedicated servers).

Comment: Rust does not have dedicated servers ( maybe a few? ). Now that you mention it, Slow internet shouldn't affect the first loading screen, but it probably influences the server loading screen as you say. I didn't though about have internet issues since I always saw the loading screen as the initial one.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot launch Rust in the new version, I would close all extra tabs (Skype, TeamSpeak (which should be fine if you are in a low quality voice chat room, which uses less bandwidth), RaidCall, things that use alot of bandwidth), and launch it at poorest graphics.

Becareful of the ping of the server you are on. The Official server has lots of players and buildings, so that could be affecting your ping. Join Community or Modded servers with not that many people and see if your ping goes down.

If that doesn't work, you might have to play what Garry classifies the "Old Version" of Rust. You can access it with the launch options before starting the game. Still a good game, it just doesn't have awesome graphics and an improved interface like the new version.

I would upgrade your rig. I personally need to upgrade my GeForce GTX 660 Ti graphics card.